# jQuery plugin callback - jQuery Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, boilerplatejs

I'm using [jquery boilerplate](https://github.com/jquery-boilerplate/jquery-boilerplate/blob/master/src/jquery.boilerplate.js) template for my plugin. I need to deliver some callback from this plugin. This callback need to be some variable with offsets coordinates.

```
var coordinates = {
    x: x2, y: y2
};
```

I try to delegate this callback like this:

```
;(function ($, window, document) {

/* 'use strict'; */

// default options
var name = "plugin",
    defaults = {};

// constructor
function plugin (options, callback) {
    this.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this.init();
    this.callback = callback;
}

plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
            x2 = (e.pageX - offset.left),
            y2 = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
            var coordinates = {
                x: x2, y: y2
            };
            this.callback(coordinates);
        });
    }
};

// initialize
$.fn[name] = function (options, callback) {
    return this.each(function() {
        if (!$.data(this, "plugin_" + name)) {
            $.data(this, "plugin_" + name, new plugin(options, callback));
        }
    });
};

})(jQuery, window, document);
```

I have an arror that callback is not a method for this object. Can anybody help?

Comment: Please provide more information on how you call your callback.

Comment: This is all what i have, i don't have idea how to do this...

Comment: I don't believe you. Are you saying you replaced `function Plugin(){...}` with that itzy bitzy piece of code? If so, your call to your callback is *completely* out of place. Do you have a link to your code somewhere online? Like a Gist?

Comment: `this.callback(coordinates);` makes no since where it is located.

Comment: @Derija93 this is only a peace of code, check out jquery boilerplate model, i need delegate some offset coordinates to some variable, maybe callback is not a god idea...

Comment: I did check it out. That's why I don't believe you. That's also why your call to your callback would be completely out of place, or in other words out of context. My guess is not that a callback won't work, but that you're using it wrongly. That's why I need to see HOW you're using it, that's why I'm asking for more code or a live demo...

Comment: see, now THAT makse sense. It isn't working there because `this` isn't what you think it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focus on how and especially **where** you call your callback:

```
plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
        var offset = $(this).offset(),
            x2 = (e.pageX - offset.left),
            y2 = (e.pageY - offset.top);

        $(document).on('mouseup', function() {
            var coordinates = {
                x: x2, y: y2
            };
            this.callback(coordinates);
        });
    }
};
```

You are creating an ***anonymous*** nested function. Anonymous functions by default have `this === window`.

---

Edit: Thanks to KevinB's comment, I noticed that my previous statement wasn't true for all cases, simply because it is possible to change the context of functions by calling `.apply()` and `.call()`, which jQuery does in order to allow you to simply use `$(this)` to access the element which triggered the event.

What I had in mind is that, if anonymous functions are called without these two methods, they, then `this === window`. But this is also true for methods which are called directly as functions, not as methods. The following won't work either.

```
var obj = { foo : 'foo', bar : function(){console.log(this.foo);} };
$(document).on('mouseup', obj.bar);
```

First of all because of the aforementioned change of context that jQuery does when calling the callback, 2nd because of a simple rule of thumb: *the context is whatever is to the left of the dot*. When calling a callback like this: `callback()`, nothing is to the left of the dot, i.e. `this === null` (don't hit me) which doesn't exist, so it defaults to `this === window`.

---

The fix to this is fairly easy: simply introduce a new variable that reference the instance of your plugin. This variable is commonly called `that`. Minor changes should accomplish your goal:

```
init: function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset(),
        x2 = (e.pageX - offset.left),
        y2 = (e.pageY - offset.top),
        that = this;

    $(document).on('mouseup', function(){
        var coordinates = {
            x: x2, y: y2
        };
        that.callback(coordinates);
    });
}
```

But beware: the way your plugin currently works, it will attach a listener to the `mouseup` event *each time it is run*. You don't need that many... especially since it will result in lags if you run the plugin a lot. I'd suggest to hook up the event listener once and call all callbacks one by one once the event has been triggered.

Comment: *"Anonymous functions always have this === window"* that is wrong, however your solution will fix it. in this case, `this` is `document`.

Comment: @KevinB That... is true. Because jQuery invokes the function by using `.call()`. I should add *by default*, thank you.

Comment: still i have this error: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'callback'

Comment: @Lukas That shouldn't happen. Make sure you put `that = this` **not** inside your anonymous function as it wouldn't make a difference to what you had before. It **has to be** in the scope of `init`. Note that `HTMLDocument` is the "class" of `document`, which supports my guess.